# Notice from Openfire Server to android user

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, notice

I am developing an application in android using XMPP with openfire server..I want to develop a notice board application in android client side...And in the notice board all the data are retrieve from the server post by the administrator from openfire server. Can it be possible to post the data from openfire server so that we can receive notice in client. Though there is the feature to send message to all online users but I want to built like a notice so that admin can post something in the notice board and user can click on notice heading to read the full news.
I am sorry if there is any plugin to do this one..

Answer (score 1):

The Publish Subscribe extension sounds like an ideal candidate: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html

It allows clients to subscribe to a feed (in this case the server notice board) and get notified when new items are posted. Depending on how you've configured it (there are a lot of options both in the client and Openfire, it's worth taking a look) the client will either receive a notification of a new entry and then need to request the full story from the server, or receive the full payload in the notification.